# Unable to figure out how to retrieve data from a service class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've created a service class, where the only job is to get the name of the person on LinkedIn. I'm using `Mechanize`to achieve this.

```
class LinkedinProfile

  attr_reader :page

  def initialize(url)
    @page = url
  end

  def run
    agent = Mechanize.new
    agent.log = Mechanize.new 'mech.log'
    agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
    linkedin_page = agent.get(@page)

    first_name  ||= linkedin_page.at(".fn").text.split(" ", 2)[0].strip if linkedin_page.at(".fn")
  end


end
```

my assumption is that ruby returns the last line, but I'm wrong in this case. I'm trying to find a way to retrieve it after I run

```
liprofile = LinkedinProfile.new('url')
```

essentially something like

```
liprofile.first_name
```

is preferred, thus I'd need a new method, but I'm not certain on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of things you need to do

1. You need to define that firstname in your initialize method
2. Add firstname to access_reader like below in order to read values from the class instances
3. Then call the run method when the class gets initialized.

like below

```
class LinkedinProfile 
  attr_reader :page, :first_name

def initialize(url)
  @page = url
  @first_name = nil
  self.run
end

def run
  agent = Mechanize.new
  agent.log = Mechanize.new 'mech.log'
  agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
  linkedin_page = agent.get(@page)

  first_name  ||= linkedin_page.at(".fn").text.split(" ", 2)[0].strip if linkedin_page.at(".fn")
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

you should call like this instead:

```
liprofile = LinkedinProfile.new('url').run
```

You're never running the method that actually pulls the profile information, only initializing the class.

Also, it's not necessary, but service methods often are implemented with a `call` (rather than `run` in your case) method for consistency.

Comment: services often implemented with `perform` rather than `call` or `run` :)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko, I've never seen perform before - I guess as long as you maintain internal consistency it doesn't matter.  You could name your method #do_it! if you really wanted :P